# Ajax PHP inserto to MySQL utf-8 characters do not work

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, utf-8

I have this javascript which collects data and sends to php:

```
$('a#correct').click(function(event){

                    trid = $(this).closest("tr").attr('id');
                    word = $('tr#'+trid+' td#word').html();
                    translation = $('tr#'+trid+' td#translation input').val();

                    if(translation.length==0)
                    {
                        //validation
                        alert('Can not be empty');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        vid = $('tr#'+trid+' td#vid').html();
                        to_lang = $('#to_lang').val();

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "word_actions.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "JSON",
                            data: {
                                    'action': 'correct',
                                    'word':word,
                                    'translation':translation,
                                    'to_lang' : to_lang,
                                    'value_id' : vid,
                                  },
                            success: function(data){
                                        $('tr#'+trid+' td#catalog').html(data['catalog']);
                                        $('tr#'+trid+' td#word').html(data['word']);
                                        $('tr#'+trid+' td#translation input').val(data['translation']);
                                     }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

In server side I have this php file:

```
$word = $_POST['word'];
            $translation = $_POST['translation'];
            $to_lang = $_POST['to_lang'];
            $value_id = $_POST['value_id'];

            if(strlen($word)!=0 && strlen($translation)!=0 &&
               strlen($to_lang)!=0 && strlen($value_id)!=0)
            {
                //insert to monitor
                $config  = new Config();

                $mysql = mysqli_connect($config->m_host, $config->m_user, 
                                    $config->m_password, $config->m_database);

                if(mysqli_connect_errno())
                {
                    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error();
                }

                //select from catalogs_values that not checked by given user
                $sql = "INSERT INTO monitor(userid, valueid, name, langid, translate) 
                                     VALUES('$user_id', '$value_id', '$word', '$to_lang', '$translation')";

                $query = mysqli_query($mysql, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysql));

                //select 10 identical words and insert it to checked add users table
            }
```

The problem is that in MySQL table I get wrong encoding, for example for NON-ASCII characters I receive: `Ð“Ð¾Ð½Ð´ÑƒÑ€Ð°Ñ` 
MySQL's character set is utf8_general_ci. Where can be the problem?

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: I meant if you have problem reading from the database and rendering correctly your HTML, no matter how they look on database. I have too utf8_general_ci and for unicode characters i see the same.

Comment: I guess my problem is between ajax and php, because when I just echo the result in php, it gives me that error

Comment: Do you have `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n");` in the top of your php?

Comment: Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Comment: I dont understand where you get the error, in the success callback of jquery? point me

Comment: @vlzvl in php file I do not get utf-8 string when sent from jquery ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML page has to be shipped as UTF-8 (since this is where the user inputs data). You can accomplish this by setting `header('content-type: text/html; charset:utf-8');` or by outputting appropriate  META tags in the `head` tag. Then you have to call `mysql_set_charset('utf-8')` in your PHP script to specify that the data you want to INSERT is UTF-8. It should work then.

Comment: What do you mean by "shipped as UTF-8"?

Comment: If your server also sends charset-headers (which some do by default), this will overwrite the meta tag. You can control the network traffic tab in your browsers developer tools or take a look at the encoding which is currently used by your browser (e.g. you can find this in the menu bar under OS X). If this is set to `automatic`, it also shows what character encoding it automatically set. If unsure, just provide the header call too.

Comment: My server sends Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Comment: I tried to change Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 to Content-Type: text/html; charset:utf-8 I does not work neither

Comment: Just control which charset your browser evaluates to. (You can also see there, if you accidentally set it to a manual charset, which would break your functionality too)